# WWW Redirects to HTTP

Tags: apache, redirect, plesk

My website (which content is an empty, standard apache welcome screen) tries to redirect from www.example.nl to example.nl

I do not have an .htaccess setup, just basic Plesk configuration.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this is a question?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have Plesk 11.5 on Linux.

Check Hosting settings of your domain and find "Preferred domain" option, change it to "None" to switch off this 301 redirect.

[image]